Why the matrix normal distribution is not estimated with this "method of moments"?
According to the Wikipedia Page, a random matrix $\bf{X}\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times q}$ follows a matrix normal distribution $\cal{MN}(\bf M, \bf U, \bf V)$ means that
$$ \text{vec}(\bf X) \sim \cal N ( \mathrm{vec} (\bf M), \bf V \otimes \bf U),$$
where $\bf M \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times q}$, $\bf U \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$, and $\bf V \in \mathbb{R}^{q\times q}$.
Suppose we have observed matrix-valued data $\bf X_1, \dots, \bf X_n$, which are assumed to be i.i.d. realizations of $\cal{MN}(\bf M, \bf U, \bf V)$. Then, the MLE has the estimate $\hat{\bf M}$ as the usual sample mean, and $\bf U$, $\bf V$ given by the following iterative procedure:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{\bf U} = \frac{1}{nq} \sum_{i=1}^n (\bf X_i - \bf M) \hat{\bf V}^{-1} (\bf X_i - \bf M)^\top, \\
\hat{\bf V} = \frac{1}{np} \sum_{i=1}^n (\bf X_i - \bf M)^\top \hat{\bf U}^{-1} (\bf X_i - \bf M).
\end{aligned}
$$
I understand the MLE framework, but I wonder why this method does not work: Notice from the same Wikipedia page that
$$\begin{aligned}
\bf E[(\bf X - \bf M) (\bf X - \bf M)^\top] = \bf U\, \mathrm{tr}(\bf V), \\
\bf E[(\bf X - \bf M)^\top (\bf X - \bf M)] = \bf V\, \mathrm{tr}(\bf U).
\end{aligned}$$
As $\bf U$ and $\bf V$ are not identifiable up to a scaling factor, we pose the additional restriction $\mathrm{tr}(\bf V) = q$. Then, I think it is plausible to estimate by:
$$\begin{aligned}
\hat{\bf U} = \frac{1}{nq} \sum_{i=1}^n (\bf X_i - \bf M) (\bf X_i - \bf M)^\top, \\
\hat{\bf V} = \frac{1}{n\operatorname{tr}(\hat{\bf U})} \sum_{i=1}^n (\bf X_i - \bf M)^\top (\bf X_i - \bf M).
\end{aligned}$$
However, the second approach is not aligned with the MLE. Where did it go wrong?

When you wrote n\,\mathrm{tr}( etc., you were manually adding horizontal space. With n\operatorname{tr}( etc., the horizontal spacing varies with the context with no need to add it manually.
